# iPhone Simulator Crash after upgrading to XCode 3.2.3

Tags: crash, ios-simulator, ios4

I just installed the new XCode with iPhone SDK 4.0. On my project, I set version 4.0 as my base version, as deployment target, 3.0 is selected.

Before the update, everything went fine. Now, if I run the iPad simulator, everything still works fine. But when I try to run it in the iPhone simulator, the app crashes before the start. I don't even come to the first line in appDidFinishLaunching. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a LOT,

Stefan

Comment: i even don't make it into the main method... according to the debugger, i'm stuck at the 'interface' of the main-method... :(

Comment: it says "SIGABRT" before the main method... don't know if that helps anyone anything...

Comment: if i use the release configuration with the same settings, it works... strange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some hours of searching, I finally found the problem: I had to switch the "generate profiling code" option off...

Answer (score 0):

Is the target SDK iPhoneSimulator 3.2?  By default the target is iPhoneSimulator 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

where is the swith: "generate profiling code" option?

Comment: select target => get info => build tab => "generate profiling code"... found it?